# Frontend Profile - Listing out Radio Buttons

Tags: templating, form, field

In the [official documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/user-profile-form) it explains how to let users customize user fields in the frontend, such as:

```
<label for="bio">Bio</label>
<textarea id="bio" name="fields[bio]">{{ currentUser.bio }}</textarea>
```

However I set some user profile fields that are Radio Buttons and can't find anywhere on how to output the field options in a form. I want to do something like:

```
<select id="radioButtons" name="fields[radioButtons]">
  {% for option in fields.profile.myRadioButtons %}
    <option value="option">{{ option | title }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

But obviously 'fields' isn't a twig variable. Is there a way to do something similar to the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the field using `currentUser.fieldHandle`; and the 'labels' and 'values' of the field by looping through the `options` attribute. You can also set the selected state by checking each option for the `option.selected` property.

```
<select id="radioButtons" name="fields[myRadioButton]">
    {% for option in currentUser.myRadioButton.options %}
        <option value="{{ option.value }}" {% if option.selected %}checked{% endif %}>{{ option.label }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. That answers other questions I had as well. Thanks Douglas